# How do I format syntax on an API call to page through the results?

Tags: python-2.7, api, curl, pagination, python-requests

I am using the SeatGeek API to pull some data for sporting events. The results of the call I get show 145,000+ results returned in the metadata:

> meta : {u'per_page': 10, u'total': 145419, u'geolocation': None, u'page': >1, u'took': 7}
>   in_hand : {}

When I look at the "Pagination" section of the API documentation, it gives examples of how to format the syntax in order to see more results per page, or to return a different page than the first one:

> $curl 'https://api.seatgeek.com/2/venues?per_page=25&page=3'

But I can't get it to call successfully with the authorization I've been given from SeatGeek:

> $curl https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET

I have tried using curl and python requests. I have tried putting the pagination syntax first and the "clientid/secret" second. I've tried putting the "clientid/secret" first. I've emailed the mods for the API to no avail.

This is the first API call I've ever made, so I'm sure there's some tiny formatting error I'm making.
The calls return successfully when I'm not using pagination. I just can't view more than one page of the results, and I'd like to view everything.

Thank you.

Comment: What does a call to `https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET&per_page=25&page=3` return? That should work.

Comment: You are a saint. I was missing the ampersand prior to the "per_page." Worked flawlessly. I was putting a question mark there. How do I give you rep?

Comment: I've posted this as an answer so this question can be marked as having an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of completeness and closure, I'm posting this as an answer:

OP used `?` instead of `&` between the URL parameters. The correct URL is `https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&clien‌​t_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&per_page=25&page‌​=3`.